# Should static variable in be visible in a separate project?

Tags: c#, .net, static, scope, visibility

If a `Visual Studio 2010` solution contains two `C#` projects where the second projects references the first project:

If a `public` `static` variable is declared in a class in the first project, should it be visible to a class in the second project?

Comment: agreed, this seems like a valid question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and no. It all depends on the *access modifier*

First off, the second project has to have a reference to the first.

Second, the owning object has to be marked `public` and not `internal`.

Finally, the field/variable itself has be marked as `public` and not `internal`/`private`/`protected`

Comment: Yes, many times. If you post some code we might be able to assist further.

Comment: and just to add another twist, project A can have its internals visible to project B, in which case, public or internal work.

Answer (score 1):

It will be visible if you make it `public`. By default it's `private`.

Of course, you need a reference to the other project.

Cheers

EDIT: It goes without saying that the class itself must be `public`.

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string zaza = "zaza";
}
```

Comment: Yes, why ? Are you still having issues with it ?